# QAbstractItemModel in QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qabstractitemmodel

I have to create items based on the file system in the directory. it is mandatory that i have to use QGraphicsView and not  (QTreeView/QListView) so how i can manage to hold a QModel for the graphicsScene. can any one help me suggest or refer an example of how i can load QFileModel with the QGraphicsScene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `QFileModel` for it. Use `QDir::entryInfoList` to get list of files and `QFileSystemWatcher` to track modification of file system.

Comment: it is a very good idea, but how i can constantly rename, delete and copy/move using the QDir::entryInfoList because i have to handle almost all the functionality in the file system through my graphicsview

Comment: You don't need to use `QDir::entryInfoList` to rename, delete or remove files. You need to use corresponding API for that: `QDir::rename`, `QDir::rmpath` and other.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one easy way to do this, add view with model to the scene. Yes, it is still `QTreeView/QListView`, but you get all advantages of `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene`, such as rotation, interaction etc.

```
//fill the model and set model to view
ui->tableView->setParent(0);
QGraphicsProxyWidget * proxyView = ui->graphicsView->scene()->addWidget(ui->tableView);
proxyView->setRotation(45);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for te reply ..actually i have to show the item completly different with the file name inside the folder structure with items (not a single item but a group of items) not on a table or tree